# NodeJS and Mongoose with Mongodb sharding issue

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I have been using NodeJS, MongooseJS with Mongodb. It is throwing the following error when i try to insert an record in mongodb using mongooseJS

```
"MongoError: right object doesn't have full shard key"
```

FYI: MongoDB Table having shard key

Please tell me how to resolve this issue! and what is that error mean?

Comment: Are you inserting an object that is part of your shard key? It sounds like maybe your trying to insert without a key that is also a shard key.

Answer (score 0):

When you are inserting any object into **Mongo** collection which has shard key, object should have all shard keys (i.e. full shard key).

As mongodb's doc says:

> All (non-multi)updates, upserts, and inserts
>   must include the current shard key."

current shard key in the sense all the shard key which are currently applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose 2.5.3 has support for sharding, just include the shardkey in the schema options and Mongoose does the rest.

```
var LoginSchema = new Schema({attribut: String}, 
                             { shardkey: { at: 1, _user: 1 }}
                            )
```